# Encryption of ID in Django using sqlite3 while storing the ID in database

Tags: python, django, database, encryption, sqlite

I have been trying to save a model using django and sqlite3 through a form.
Here are the codes to it:

This is the **/home/secure/secure_db/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^create/$',views.create_db, name='create_db') ]
```

This is the **/home/secure/secure_db/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse  from django.shortcuts import render  from .models import Detail from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

def index(request):
    template = 'index.html'
    return render(request, template)

def create_db(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST['id']
        name = request.POST['name']

        enc_id = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(id, rounds=12000, salt_size=32)

        Detail.objects.create(
            id = enc_id,
            name = name
        )
    return HttpResponse('')
```

This is the **/home/secure/secure_db/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

class Detail(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def verify_id(raw_id):
        return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(raw_id, self.id)
```

This is the **/home/secure/secure_db/templates/index.html**

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >

    $(document).on('submit','#new_user_form',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/secure_db/create',
            data:{
                id:$('#id').val(),
                name:$('#name').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success:function () {
                alert("Created New User");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="new_user_form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    User ID:<br>    
    <input type="number" name="id" id="id"><br>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am navigating to http://localhost:8000/secure_db and entering the id and name, the alert is not appearing and the data are not getting stored into database. If I am storing the data through navigating into admin panel, the data is getting stored but in the plain format and the id is not getting encrypted.

Comment: Why do you want to hash the id? What is a potential threat and how does hashing the id prevent that threat? Other than that, you haven't given nearly enough information for us to help you debug this problem. Does the request fire? What is the response? Do you get any errors, either in javascript or in the response?

Comment: This is a project given to me by my mentors. Hashing the id is just the start. There are other things that I would look into after this step. When I open the form and submit the id and name it reverts back to the same page without any alert or any warning or errors and the data is not stored into the db.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.